# Python Machine learning use multiple stock datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

first I want to say that I am a newbie in Machine learning, so I hope you can help me. I want to **predict stock prices** using machine learning, it works for me using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOLSGMEEwlI) tutorial. To get **more accurate** than [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at5yB.png), I thought it may help using more data.

Now I have more CSV files with data but from other stocks and from other companies, now my question is, **can I** use files from different stocks to get more accurate and **how** could I do it?

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974005/reinforcement-learning-using-multiple-stock-ticker-s-datasets) one Stackoverflow Question which describes my problem, but the answer doesnt help me. It says normalizing the data after combining it. But I dont understand whats ment with combining the datasets, because when I just add the CSV files under each other, the model wouldnt know which data is for which Ticker. I hope you understand my Problem and you can help me.

---

### Here is the code, which I think is relevant:

---

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'aapl_data.csv')
df = df[['close']]

# Create variable to predict 'x' days out the future
future_days = 25
# Create a column (target) shifted 'x' days up
df['Prediction'] = df['close'].shift(-future_days)

# Create feature data set, convert it to numpy array and remove last 'x' rows/days
X = np.array(df.drop(['Prediction'], 1))[:-future_days]
# Create target data set (y), convert it to numpy array get all of the target values except the last 'x' rows/days
y = np.array(df['Prediction'])[:-future_days]

# Split the data to 75% training and 25% testing
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

x_train = np.nan_to_num(x_train)
y_train = np.nan_to_num(y_train)
tree = DecisionTreeRegressor().fit(x_train, y_train)
```

PS: You would also help me, changing the title when needed or telling me what I have to google to find an answer, because I dont think that I am the first person with this idea, but I dont know how this "problem" is called.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try keep training the same model with each new stock dataset.  Just save you model after each training.  This is my suggestion, not necessarily the right answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).